# How to join (FULL OUTER) two Lists in Scala?

Tags: scala, list

I have two Lists: `dec_tyres` and `jan_tyres`:

```
scala> dec_tyres
res21: List[(String, Int)] = List((007139::21,10), .....

scala> jan_tyres
res22: List[(String, Int)] = List((005179::24,2), ..... 

scala> dec_tyres.length
res19: Int = 71

scala> jan_tyres.length
res20: Int = 82
```

Now to join these I'm doing:

```
val mb = jan_tyres.toMap
val tyres_count = dec_tyres.flatMap{case (ka,va) => mb.get(ka).map(vb => (ka,va,vb))}.toList
```

Which gives me:

```
scala> tyres_count
res23: List[(String, Int, Int)] = List((007139::21,10,8), .....

scala> tyres_count.length
res24: Int = 53
```

This is computing an inner join and giving me only 53 records, where I'm expecting 100 records.

All the records where both of the `dec_tyres` and `jan_tyres` do not have a common key are scraped. Instead I want that record with the particular key instead a zero as the respective value.

The solution is hence a "Full Outer Join", which I'm really struggling with.

Comment: Can you turn this into a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ? I'm a little concerned of the type signature of that list being (String, Int) there is some extremely odd type conversion happening that could be cleared up with explicitly typed variables.

Comment: @RyanTheLeach Not getting you mate. I have two lists of type List(String, Int); String being the key. I want to join them to form List(String, Int, Int). And this join should be a full outer join.

Comment: Is your String/id/key seriously of the form "007139::21" ? It's confusing, as it looks rather like 'cons'

Comment: @RyanTheLeach Yes. It is a composite String I've explicitly created. There is absolutely no issue with it, I'm sure. I just want to outer join my two lists with those keys.

Comment: Yeah just misunderstanding on my part due to lack of context, all good :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want a `(String, Int, Int)` result for every unique `String` from the two `(String, Int)` input lists?

```
val janMap = jan_tyres.toMap  // for fast lookup
val decMap = dec_tyres.toMap

val tyres_count = (jan_tyres ++ dec_tyres).map(_._1).distinct.map{ k =>
  (k, decMap.getOrElse(k, 0), janMap.getOrElse(k, 0))
}
```

Combine the lists (`++`), keep only the key strings (`map(_._1)`), remove duplicates (`distinct`), change each key (`k`) into a tuple using the `Map`s to retrieve the `Int` values (`map{...}`).

Comment: can you explain the last map though?

Comment: Expanded explanation added.

Comment: I split this answer into steps, but was unable to get it to work.

Error:(10, 35) value distinct is not a member of scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int]
lazy val distinct = intermediate.distinct
                                 ^

where intermediate is jan ++ dec . map(_._1)

Comment: @RyanTheLeach, Combine `++` the original `List`s, not the `Map`s. Those are just used in the final step, the result tuple.

Comment: My bad it's good. But I can't fix and upvote until its edited

Comment: It was longer then the 5 minutes.

Comment: The solution is elegent. Just a follow up question @jwvh:

For lists with more than 2 dimensions i.e. List[String, Int, Int]; toMap gives error.

Any suggestion as to how to tweak your code for joing such lists.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to generify it over arity, I think that's changing the question enough that it may warrant a new question..

Comment: A `Map` key can only point to one value so you need to change the 2 `Int` elements into a single value (a tuple). In other words: `List[(String,Int,Int)]` to `List[(String,(Int,Int))]` to `Map[String,(Int,Int)]`. Something like: `lst.map(x => x._1 -> (x._2,x._3)).toMap`

Comment: Alright! Posting a new one then! @RyanTheLeach my targeted problem is a multi-value map right?

Comment: Alright! @jwvh and I can then rollback values from that tuple right?

Comment: A multimap generally doesn't care about order of the values in the map, and may constrain the values to be unique I think.

I don't know the term for it, but I'm imagining the output as a table.

Comment: @PrathamSolanki, you can access tuple elements by their index (`._1`, `._2`, etc.) but @RyanTheLeach is correct that trying to generalize tuples of different lengths is different than generalizing lists. In fact, it shouldn't be attempted. You should consider changing your data representation instead.

Comment: I'd suggest something like this, if you were going to ask again. https://gist.github.com/ryantheleach/fd71674e1e8e683657b5d469fdee659d